# A str, Segment or object with __rich_console__ method is required

Tags: python, import, terminal, console, rich

I'm trying to use the rich library in Python to create a live updating console application. However, I'm encountering an issue when attempting to use a Console object within a Live context. Here's a minimal example of the code:

```
from rich.console import Console
from rich.live import Live
from rich.control import Control

def minimal_example():
    console = Console()

    with Live(console, refresh_per_second=1, auto_refresh=False) as live:
        while True:
            try:
                console.print("Working...")
                console.print(Control())
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    minimal_example()
```

When running this code, I encounter the following error:

```
rich.errors.NotRenderableError: Unable to render <console width=132 ColorSystem.WINDOWS>; A str, Segment or object with __rich_console__ method is required
```

It seems like the Console object is causing issues within the Live context. How can I resolve this error and properly use the Console object within Live for live updating of the console output?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You're telling the `Live` to render the console instead of using it as a console. You tell it to use a particular console as its console with the `console` keyword argument.